# Why are breakpoints still being hit in a file that was added to the ignore list in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I added a mouse click event listener breakpoint in Windows Chrome (Version 113.0.5672.93)
and added the event-handler.js file to the ignore list. It's a Bootstrap js file.
In a mouse click on the webpage which uses Bootstrap, line 104, as shown below, keeps getting broken into by a breakpoint set by Chrome.

I am expecting this file to be totally ignored. Why are breakpoints in the file being hit? The file is in the ignore list, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: We are currently discussing whether to change this behavior. (https://crbug.com/1431428) Can you help me understand your scenario better? In particular, how and why is this breakpoint being set?

Comment: I didn't set the breakpoint. Chrome is breaking into that line and I don't want it to. That's why I added the file to the ignore list.